# Can't view image from postgres

Tags: java, spring, image

I have an entity class - Products

```
@Data
@Entity
@Table(name = "products")
public class Products {
    
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;
    @Column(name = "name")
    @Size(min = 3, max = 40)
    private String name;
    @Column(name = "price")
    @Min(1)
    @Max(10000)
    private int price;
    @Column(name = "serial")
    @Min(1)
    @Max(1000000)
    private int serial;
    @Column(name="picture")
    private byte[] picture; //other code
```

I'm saving path to my image:

```
@Bean
CommandLineRunner runner(ProductService productService, UserService userService) throws IOException {
    byte[] array = Files.readAllBytes(Paths.get("src/main/resources/static/img/mask_black.png"));
    return args -> {
        productService.saveProduct(new Products(11L, "black mask", 100, 11111, array));
```

Image is seen in table like 650x458, JPEG image 25,45 kB
and here is my html template:

```
<tr th:each="products : ${products}">
                <td th:text="${products.name}"></td>
                <td th:text="${products.price}"></td>
                <img src="${products.picture}" width="100" height="100"/> //some other code
```

but when i open a page i dont see my image, only empty square. What am i doing wrong?
p.s. also i have repository, service and controller classes, but it's standard like in any crud project.

Comment: HTML img src attribute should contain an URL (in text form) only, not a byte array. It may either be a link to a separate resource, or an embedded data URL as @ShaileshJain posted below. If you use the data URL, you need to base64 encode your data (the picture array).

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
<img src="data:image/jpg;base64, ${products.picture}">
```